# Java Eclipse Strange mark on the screen

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

I am a student who learns Java program.
If you look at the attached file, there is a strange mark on the screen, how should I remove it?
[image: Strange marks]

Comment: Looks like new line is interpreted as a symbol, which text editor or ide you use?

Answer (score 1):

You might have enabled Show whitespace Characters option in eclipse. Disable it.

[image]